How to calculate weight of larger equipment?
I recently looked up the stat block for a Storm Giant. Unsurprisingly, it has a STR score of 29 and is a huge creature. It attacks in melee with a Greatsword. However, I was surprised to see that it was wearing scale mail. After some quick calculations, I think I'm missing something obvious somewhere in terms of weight.
So, let's start with calculating the carrying capacity of this giant.
Quoting the rules on lifting and carrying:

Carrying Capacity. Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, [...]

29 STR x 15 lb/STR = 435 lb
Now, there is a rule for being bigger than a medium size creature in the same rules:

Size and Strength. Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny creatures can carry less. For each size category above Medium, double the creature's carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. [...]

Since the Storm Giant is huge, which is 2 size categories above medium:
435lb x 2 x 2 = 1740 lb.
That's a pretty good amount of carrying capacity. But the Scale Mail (normally listed at 45 lb) they are wearing is also not medium size. The only place I could go to for weight changes is Enlarge/Reduce, which when Enlarging an object says:

Enlarge. The target’s size doubles in all dimensions, and its weight is multiplied by eight. This growth increases its size by one category – from Medium to Large, for example.

Using this knowledge, I simply assumed that the weight of Huge Scale Mail would be the same as a medium sized weapon that theoretically would benefit from 2 Enlarge/Reduce spells (I say theoretically, because you can't benefit from the same spell twice at the same time). So:
45 lb x 8 x 8 = 2880 lb, which is above their carrying capacity.
I figure that the intention of the Storm Giant stat block is NOT that they are currently carrying above their carrying capacity and end up pinned to the ground by the weight of their own armor. While I imagine the rules of Enlarge/Reduce only apply to specifically Enlarge/Reduce (after all, damage of enlarged weapons don't work like the oversized weapons rules), I doubt the weight of the scale mail on a Storm Giant would be the same as the weight of the scale mail you could put on a Medium-sized creature. The same goes for their Greatsword.
So, how much does it weigh? How should I calculate how much their armor and their greatsword weigh in a way that doesn't end up with the storm giant being beyond their carrying capacity, and is there any official ruling on that?
If there is no official ruling, how would you rule the weight of that greatsword? Let's say a medium size Fighter or Barbarian gets really hyped and uses something like a Potion of Growth and decides they want to try to kill a few things with the huge greatsword.

Hi Shawn, I've closed this question as a duplicate.  Duplicates are a good thing, as they give those looking for answers in a search engine more change of landing on the right question.  Please read the linked question, and if it does not contain the answer you are seeking, edit your question to explain why.  Once your question is edited, it is eligible to be re-opened.

See especially Carcer's comment here, which addresses more directly your question about larger equipment.

Ah, shoot, I missed the sprite question when doing my research. Sorry about that.
